# Use leaflet with VueJS3 leads to an error

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, vuejs3

I'm trying to display interactive maps in my VueJS3 app.

I found a code that works:

```html
<template>
  <div id="mapContainer"></div>
</template>

<script>
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import L from 'leaflet';

export default {
  name: 'LeafletMap',
  data() {
    return {
      map: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.map = L.map('mapContainer').setView([46.05, 11.05], 5);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    }).addTo(this.map);
    //use a mix of renderers
    var customPane = this.map.createPane('customPane');
    var canvasRenderer = L.canvas({ pane: 'customPane' });
    customPane.style.zIndex = 399; // put just behind the standard overlay pane which is at 400
    L.marker([50, 14]).addTo(this.map);

    L.marker([53, 20]).addTo(this.map);
    L.marker([49.5, 19.5]).addTo(this.map);
    L.marker([49, 25]).addTo(this.map);
    L.marker([-10, 25]).addTo(this.map);
    L.marker([10, -25]).addTo(this.map);
    L.marker([0, 0]).addTo(this.map);
  },
  onBeforeUnmount() {
    if (this.map) {
      this.map.remove();
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
#mapContainer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
</style>
```

But as soon as I import a custom geoJSON, like this:

```js
import France from '@/assets/carto/France.geojson';
```

I have this in my console:

> [Vue Router warn]: uncaught error during route navigation: vue-router.mjs:35:17
> SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':' vue-router.mjs:3451:20
> [Vue Router warn]: Unexpected error when starting the router: SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'
> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'France.geojson:2:8

What is wrong?

By the way, `France.geoJSON` is a classic geoJSON file:

```json
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [5.829184048326689, 45.93827339383888], ...
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": { "dep": "01", "reg": "84", "libgeo": "Ain" }
    }, ...
```

Comment: ...and what's the content of line 3451 of the compiled `vue-router.mjs`?

Comment: I added an error line. It seems the error comes from the France.geojson file but this file is quite normal...

Comment: Time to run that file through a JSON linter.

Comment: Try with another test geoJSON to be sure that the french one is working great.

Comment: @IvanSanchez that is what I did and it said it was a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if I write

```js
import France from '@/assets/carto/france.json';
```

After having changed the name of the file, it works.
I still don't know why the extension matters.

Comment: It's the opposite actually. There is probably no default loader for `.geojson`, hence your bundle doesn't know what to do with that extension.